# gdb can not load shared libraries on iphone 5.1.1

Tags: ios, load, gdb, shared-libraries

I'm trying to dump memory of executed App on iOS (with gdb).
But gdb can not dump any data. (Exactly, the dumped data is filled with 0x00.)

According to instructions on other website, 
when gdb attaching to a process, will start to load shared libraries.
But, mime does not load library.

Below is exact message when attaching to process.

> root# gdb -p 4570 GNU gdb 6.3.50.20050815-cvs (Fri May 20 08:08:42 UTC
>   2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. GDB is free
>   software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain
>   conditions. Type "show copying" to see the conditions. There is
>   absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "--host=arm-apple-darwin9 --target=".
>   /private/var/root/4570: No such file or directory Attaching to process
>   4570. 0x35f9f004 in ?? () (gdb)

FYI, my iPhone is 4S, iOS is 5.1.1.
Am I missed any setting for gdb?

Comment: Consider using LLDB instead, GDB is getting old...

Comment: Thank, borrrden. But I can't find LLDB for iphone in cydia. Do you know repo address that has LLDB?

Comment: That was a hugely important piece of information that you omitted....I have no idea about jailbroken stuff.

Comment: Finally I found the way.
See this article. http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/how-to-install-gnu-debugger-gdb-on-ios-5/

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this problem, add http://cydia.radare.org to cydia source and download the latest GNU Debugger (build 1708). GDB build 1708 is working for iOS 5.0+